# PHP check certain date and give output

Tags: php

I have a php script that checks which day of the week it is and then gives the opening hours for that day. (this part works) 
But I want to include holidays.
For now I'm trying if the holiday is on 5/5/2016.

For some reason it's failing..

Here is my code:

**PHP - edit**

```
<?php
    $strVerlofDag = '05/05/2016';
    if (date('d/m/Y') == $strVerlofDag);
    {
        echo 'Gesloten wegens O.H. Hemelvaart';
    }
    else
    {
        $vandaag = date("l");
        switch($vandaag)
        {
            case 'Monday':
                echo 'Maandag: 14u - 19u';
                break;
            case 'Tuesday':
                echo 'Dinsdag: 14u - 19u';
                break;
            case 'Wednesday':
                echo 'Woensdag: : 14u - 19u';
                break;
            case 'Thursday':
                echo 'Donderdag: 14u - 19u';
                break;
            case 'Friday':
                echo 'Vrijdag: : 14u - 19u';
                break;
            case 'Saturday':
                echo 'Zaterdag: 9u - 17u';
                break;
            case 'Sunday':  
                echo 'Zondag: gesloten';
                break;  
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `Saterday` that's mispelled if your function depends on spelling. Edit: which it does http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php *"l (lowercase - A full textual representation of the day of the week  Sunday through Saturday"*

Comment: and... `17pm`? either it's 17:00 in military time, or `5pm`.

Comment: I am not sure what is the logic behind using `checkdate()` function here since all it returns is true or false based on if the date is valid or not.

Comment: You might have to find a way to somehow connect or compare today's date with the holiday date(s).

Comment: cinco de mayo eh? yeah, that's a holiday; *somewhere*

Answer (score 1):

[`checkdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) always return true if it's a valid date, including all holidays (and non-holidays), so that's why your logic won't work as written.

I would think you'll need to hard code an array of your specific holiday dates, and then use something like [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to see if it's in there.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best to keep to KISS (keep it simple stupid) design whenever possible.
Why convert date formats instead of just getting the current date in the format you want?

```
$strHolidayDate = '05/05/2016';
if (date('d/m/Y') == $strHolidayDate);
{
    echo 'Closed for holiday';
}
else
{
    //... do switch logic here.
}
```

This would also let you convert the code to using an array of holiday dates (such something you're retrieve from a DB) very easily.

There is also no need to have a 'break' in your first if statement, outside of the switch.

Comment: watch my edit post. For some reason he is still failing.

Answer (score 0):

The [checkdate](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) funtion takes months and days without the leading zero (`int`)

```
bool checkdate ( int $month , int $day , int $year )
```

Valid examples:

```
checkdate(2, 29, 2016);
checkdate(9, 8, 2016);
```

---

Here's another way to achieve what you want:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set( "Europe/Lisbon" );
$holliday = new DateTime( "04/25/2016" );
$holliday->format( "m/d/Y" );
$today = new DateTime( "today" );

if( $holliday == $today ){
   echo "Holliday";
}
```

---

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/B68lnN)